# how to install pear and php unit on easyphp 12.1

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, easyphp

I tried this: [tutorial](http://webadio.com/how-to-setup-easyphp-12-0-with-php-5-4-pear-and-phpunit/) but it didn't work.
When I try use this command: *php go-pear.phar* or simple *php* I get a warning: "The program can't start because yaz4.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." I press ok and other warning: "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:wEasy\php\php5415x130416164116\ext\php_yaz.dll' - The specified module could not be found." press ok again and in the command window:

e:\wEasy\php\php5414x130416164146>php go-pear.phra
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\wEasy\php\php5414x
130416164146\ext\php_yaz.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\wEasy\php\php5414x13041
6164146\ext\php_yaz.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: go-pear.phra

e:\wEasy\php\php5414x130416164146>php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\wEasy\php\php5414x
130416164146\ext\php_yaz.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\wEasy\php\php5414x13041
6164146\ext\php_yaz.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

I found the yaz4.dll [enter heredescription here](http://php.net/manual/en/yaz.installation.php) but I don't know how can I use it :/

Regards, Zserrbo

Answer (score 0):

The file yaz4.dll is on the directory:

...easyphp_instalation...\apache\bin

You have to agregate to the PATH enviroment...

(sorry by my english, i'm mexican)